# How should we decide whether some of the logic should be implemented in front-end or backend?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a very general question regarding web design and development. How should we decide whether some of the logic should be implemented in front-end or backend? Is there a general guidance or principle on that?

Our use case: We have an internal webportal (React + AWS Lambda & API Gateway). We would like to add a new feature to the portal to forecast product sales. Users can provide an product, target date etc. The UI will show multiple the forecasted sales based on different discounts(10%, 20%,30% etc). Another feature is users upload a CSV file of collection of configurations and the UI provides results as a CSV file to download. We currently already have a external service that provide an API that takes a list of products with configs and responses forecasts for them. So our backend lambda needs to connects to that services. From my understanding we have 2 options here:

1. The backend (AWS Lambda+API Gateway) expose a simple generic API (Similar to the ML Service). It takes a list of products with configurations, and response back a list of forecasts for them. In this case, it's front-end's responsibility to construct the requests based on different use cases. For example, it needs to expand the users input with different discounts. If users upload files, it needs to parse the files and transform that to the API's request format and after receiving responses, the front-end needs to transform that to CSV file for download. Since front-end already construct the requests and handle response, backend lambda will do nothing but forward the request to the ML Service.

   - Pros:

     - the API itself is extensible. If we need more capability on UI, like drawing diagram with more configurations, we can simply reuse the same API.
   - Cons:

     - UI is heavy while backend does nothing but request forwarding. It could be heavier if we go on this path, like file parsing, creation etc.
2. The backend (Lambda+API Gateway) exposes specific APIs, not just one. It takes users' input and extends the input into a list of products with configurations (like different discounts). After that the backend calls ML Service to get forecasts and returns back the result in the format needed by front-end for front-end to render. In this case, we probably have 2 APIs. First one is for the single product case, which takes an product with other user input and responses back a list of forecasts based on different discounts. 2nd API is for file-upload-download case, which takes a file as input and response a file or URL. In this case, the front-end will be purely focusing on user experience and data rendering.

   - Pros:

     - UI can purely focus on user experience and data rendering.
   - Cons:

     - The backend API is very specific and not extensible, we have to add more APIs in the future. This is minor from development point of view because the lambda itself is based on Spring Boot so it's easy to to Add more APIs in the Controller with @RequestMapping.

I am new to web design and development so any information, guidance or reference to resources will be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is an opinion based and frankly Stackoverflow frowns upon such questions. There is no universal truth. Some believe that most if not all business logic should be in backend, but at the same time we try to delegate some of the processing heavy lifting to the client's browser since client's machine can usually do it without noticing any performance issues. At the end it is your call - make a choice and see what works.